# See only posts with watched tags

Tags: support, search, user-interface, tag-watching

I have a couple of watched tags on stack overflow, and I want to hide all answers that aren't tagged with my watched tags. Is this possible?

Comment: What's the point of watching tags without this feature? Seems like an obvious need

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This should be possible with [custom question lists](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/312781/323179). If it works as they say it does, then you can either use `intags:mine` or list your tags (my personal preference would be to have several different lists of related tags):

> [image]

You could easily access these lists via the sidebar under shortcuts:

> [image]

You can see how to opt in [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/313940/323179), but you will need to wait... I've been waiting for like a month :(

Until then, you can bookmark [the search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=intags%3amine%20is%3aq) via your browser.

Comment: I've been waiting several months to get opted in; hopefully that system will be better, I gave it my best shot to filter based on questions I'm actually interested in [yet I still get web / SQL / "devops" stuff that I can't answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VeqwC.png) and I kinda ignore the front page as a result.

Answer (score 15):

The search syntax for that is:

```
intags:mine
```

This can conveniently be used by setting up a "bookmark" or "favorite" or however your favorite browser calls it.

Comment: Is it possible to do without doing a search every time?

Comment: I added a recommendation.