# Custom Filter support an array of optional tags

Tags: feature-request, tags, custom-filter

We are only allowed to use up to 99 filter tags, which is reasonable if you look at the generated URL. But the current logic forces you to do something like this:

> `[python] and [multithreading] or [python-multithreading] or [python] and [multiprocessing] or [python-multiprocessing]....`

Now to have a custom filter that supports all of my tags I'm interested seems impossible, especially with Python. Because even if you use a [wildcard tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408952/support-wildcards-for-tags-in-custom-filter) to cover the top 20 tags you won't get much benefit from it, cause [apparently the top 20 are](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1382037/tag-search-with-wikis-and-excerpts?TagName=azure#resultSets) full of `[python]` `[python 3.x]` and `[python 3.5]`. So the idea that I had was to use simply an array of optional tags, [this seems intuitive](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/401759/13629335) for other users as well. So you could do something like `[python] and ([multithreading],[multiprocessing]..)`.

This would ease things out by filtering just the tags I'm actually interested in, without to bother by either checking each question under a general tag like [python] or to have a bunch of custom filter for each technology I'm actually interested in like `PyConcurrent`.

So I'm tagging it as [feature-request] but I'm also interested in how you all solve this issue and if you think there is one.

Comment: Related https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/375591/1595451

Comment: Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/375365/1595451 and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272607/1595451

Comment: @Rubén and what will I find there ?